How do I extract two numbers from a string and generate all numbers between them in rust
I have a user-input form which allows them to provide either a single value n or a range in the format start-end. I want to generate a vector of all numbers in the range (with just one entry in the n case).
I have the below which solves the problem:
fn parse_ports(ports: &str) -> Result<Vec<u32>, ParseError> {
    let ports: Vec<&str> = ports.split("-").collect();

    if ports.len() == 1 {
        Ok(
            ports.iter()
                .map(|x| x.parse().unwrap())
                .collect()
        )
    } else if ports.len() == 2 {
        let start: u32 = ports[0].parse().unwrap();
        let end: u32 = ports[1].parse().unwrap();

        Ok((start..end + 1).collect::<Vec<u32>>())
    } else {
        // At some point this should probably error but that is a tomorrow problem
        Ok(vec![])
    }
}

I am sure I can do this more efficiently but I'm wildly inexperienced in Rust so would appreciate any help or feedback.
I feel like I should be able to do this without the if. I also expect I can run some validation on the string rather than dealing with the len != 1 and len != 2 case in the if.

Since you already have working code and are looking for ways to improve it, this question may be more suited for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ (however, be sure to read Code Review for SO users before posting there).

Why do you want to collect the port ranges into Vecs? It might be preferable to just return a RangeInclusive object depending on your use case.

If you only have the single and pair cases, then you could use split_once().
If you always attempt to parse in the None case, then an empty string (ports), will also implicitly return an error:
use std::num::ParseIntError;

fn parse_ports(ports: &str) -> Result<Vec<u32>, ParseIntError> {
    let (start, end) = if let Some((start, end)) = ports.split_once('-') {
        let start = start.parse()?;
        let end = end.parse()?;
        (start, end)
    } else {
        let start = ports.parse()?;
        (start, start)
    };

    Ok((start..end + 1).collect())
}

Depending in what logic you need in-between, then there's various ways you can structure this logic:
fn parse_ports(ports: &str) -> Result<Vec<u32>, ParseIntError> {
    let (start, end) = match ports.split_once('-') {
        Some((start, end)) => (start, Some(end)),
        None => (ports, None),
    };

    let start = start.parse()?;
    let end = end.map(|end| end.parse()).transpose()?;

    Ok(match end {
        Some(end) => (start..=end).collect(),
        None => vec![start],
    })
}


I'm pretty sure this has the same/desired behavior and is far simpler than both examples here: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=70428958de6be4f8e717517438f2c849

@cdhowie Yes, I agree, but OP said something about having validation in-between. So I wanted to clearly separate the parsing from the collecting

It may be preferable to parse the ports into a range object and return this, depending on your use case:
use std::num::ParseIntError;
use std::ops::RangeInclusive;

const PORTS_DELIMITER: char = '-';

/// Parse a port range.
///
/// # Errors
/// Returns a [`ParseIntError`] if the port numbers could not be parsed.
///
/// # Examples
/// ```
/// use parse_ports::parse_port_range;
///
/// assert_eq!(parse_port_range("123"), Ok(123..=123));
/// assert_eq!(parse_port_range("42-1337"), Ok(42..=1337));
///
/// for (index, port) in parse_port_range("0-65535").unwrap().enumerate() {
///     assert_eq!(index as u32, port);
/// }
///
/// assert!(parse_port_range("1-10").unwrap().contains(&7));
/// ```
pub fn parse_port_range(port_range: &str) -> Result<RangeInclusive<u32>, ParseIntError> {
    let (start, end) = port_range
        .split_once(PORTS_DELIMITER)
        .unwrap_or((port_range, port_range));
    Ok(start.parse()?..=end.parse()?)
}

